# 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider' after deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I have a service which works perfectly on my loacal server in development environment, but on Heroku in production I'm getting an error `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- SidebarService <- sidebarDirective`

**CoffeeScript:**

```
app.factory 'SidebarService', ($http) ->
  Resource = {}

  Resource.getAllPhotos = () ->
    $http.get('/photos.json')

  Resource.getAlbum = () ->
    $http.get()


  Resource

app.directive 'sidebar', ['SidebarService', (SidebarService) ->

  template = ''

  initSideBar = (s, e, a) ->
    $(document).on 'click', '#all-photos', ->
      SidebarService.getAllPhotos().then (result) ->
        d = result.data
        pics = for n, pic of d
          "<div class='draggable slider__picture' id='photo-#{n}' data-type='picture' data-source='#{pic.original}' style='background: url(#{pic.thumb}) center / cover'></div>"
        template = "<div class='slider__button-back' id='button-back__all-photos'><i class='material-icons'>arrow_back</i>" +
            "<span>Back</span></div>" +
            pics.join ''
        $('#slider-pictures').empty().removeClass('slider-pictures')
        $('#slider-pictures').append(template)
        $('.draggable').draggable(
          {
            revert: true
            appendTo: 'body'
            containment: 'window'
            scroll: false
            zIndex: 100
            helper: 'clone'
          })

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: template,
    scope: {},
    link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
      initSideBar(scope, element, attributes)
    }
]
```

Where should I dig? Maybe it is because of `https` protocol on Heroku?

Comment: Looks to me that your app failed to located `sidebarDirective` directive. Make sure that the JS file containing this directive is loaded in the app html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember assets (specially js in this case) are not minified on development while in prod they get minified. These errors may be caused by a conflict during your js minification. To avoid '$injector type of errors during minification, make sure you use $inject to manually identify your dependencies for Angular components.

Take a look here, for the complete recommendation/practice the https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y091

Comment: Injection didn't help